# swiftui pickerで複数選択をしたいのですが可能でしょうか

Tags: swiftui, form

swiftui のFormからPickerを利用して選択をさせようとしています。
現状では１件、例えばType01を選択は可能ですが、type01,type02と複数を選択したいのでが可能でしょうか

```
let TypeArray = ["type01", "type02", "type03", "type04", "type05", "type06", "type07"]
@State private var selection = 0
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        Form {
            Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("type")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< TypeArray.count) { num in
                    Text(self.TypeArray[num])
                }
            }
            
・・・・略
```

Answer (score 0):

Pickerで複数選択はできないと思いますので、それに近いものを自分で書く必要があるかと思います。
もし複数選択できたらすいません。

```
struct TypeEntity: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var isTap: Bool = false
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var typeSelection: Int = 0
    @State private var showType: Bool = false
    @State private var TypeArray: [TypeEntity] = [
        TypeEntity(name: "type01"),
        TypeEntity(name: "type02"),
        TypeEntity(name: "type03"),
        TypeEntity(name: "type04"),
        TypeEntity(name: "type05"),
        TypeEntity(name: "type06"),
    ]
    var message: String {
        if TypeArray.filter({ $0.isTap }).isEmpty {
            return "選択してください"
        } else {
            var types: [String] = []
            for type in TypeArray.filter({ $0.isTap }) {
                types.append(type.name)
            }
            return types.joined(separator: ",")
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            HStack {
                Text("Type")
                Spacer()
                Button("\(message)") {
                    self.showType.toggle()
                }
            }
            if self.showType {
                ForEach(TypeArray.indices) { i in
                    HStack {
                        if TypeArray[i].isTap {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                        }
                        Text("\(TypeArray[i].name)")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        TypeArray[i].isTap.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

こんな感じで選択欄を表示させるボタンと、Typeの構造体を用意しタップされたらType構造体の`isTap`を`true`にし、それに連動してチェックマークを表示するというようにすれば複数選択のようなことが可能になります。